# dia graphics program drawing curly braces

Tags: graphics, dia

Other than (1) using bezier curves or (2) using the keyboard curly brace and increasing the font, is there a way to draw curly braces in Dia, and if so what is it?

The reason for not using the two above is the bezier curve braces don't look very polished and cant be scaled up and down, and the keyboard curly brace has a line width that is too thick once it is expanded.

I'm trying to show aggregations of processes in a flow chart.

Thanks

Comment: Sharing your bezier curve curly brace might allow others to "polish" its look a little bit. When "scaling up and down" - do you expect your curly braces keep the aspect ratio? Or do you just want the vertical sections to extend?

Comment: Import a SVG file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643243/how-do-i-import-custom-svg-shapes-into-dia

Comment: @SteffenMacke Here is how it's done in Inkscape with Bezier lines: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/86348/85254 . Just tried it in Dia, and it's just the same as shown by that link.

Answer (score 4):

Related solution, NOT curly braces, but to insert square braces in Dia you can use the SDL shape collection. The item is called "Comment." Use Properties > Flip Horizontal for closing brace.

Brace text is placed on the inside for some reason, but an attachment point supports textboxes attached to the outside.

[image]
[image]